# Android login using wsdl webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to write a login activity (authenticate user) using wsdl web service, the code is written below.Anytime I enter an username and password and click on login button nothing happens!

I can't find out why it doesn't work properly? 
This is loginActivity:

```
    userNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    passWordET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    statusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    webservicePG = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (userNameET.getText().length() != 0 && userNameET.getText().toString() != "") {
                if(passWordET.getText().length() != 0 && passWordET.getText().toString() != ""){
                    editTextUsername = userNameET.getText().toString();
                    editTextPassword = passWordET.getText().toString();
                    statusTV.setText("");
                    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                    task.execute();
                }
                else{
                    statusTV.setText("Enter Password");
                }
            } else {
                statusTV.setText("Enter Username");
            }
        }
    });
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask {


    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loginStatus = WebService.invokeLoginWS(editTextUsername, editTextPassword,"Authenticate");
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        webservicePG.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Intent intObj = new Intent(CheckLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        if(!errored){
            if(loginStatus){
                startActivity(intObj);
            }
            else{
                statusTV.setText("Username or Password Incorrect");
            }
        }
        else{
            statusTV.setText("Failed to call webservice");
        }
        errored = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        webservicePG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }


}
```

and this is webService class:

```
public class WebService {

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String URL = "http://localhost:9999/WCFServices/WCFAuthenticateUser.svc";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/Authenticate";

public static boolean invokeLoginWS(String userName,String passWord, String webMethName) {
    boolean loginStatus = false;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
    PropertyInfo unamePI = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo passPI = new PropertyInfo();
    unamePI.setName("Username");
    unamePI.setValue(userName);
    unamePI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(unamePI);
    passPI.setName("Password");
    passPI.setValue(passWord);
    passPI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passPI);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION , envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        loginStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        CheckLoginActivity.errored = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return loginStatus;
}
```

}

in continue is the webService XMLSchema:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="WCFAuthenticateUser" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:9999/WCFServices/WCFAuthenticateUser.svc?xsd=xsd5" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:9999/WCFServices/WCFAuthenticateUser.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:9999/WCFServices/WCFAuthenticateUser.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MYCMR.Common.DTO"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:9999/WCFServices/WCFAuthenticateUser.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MYCMR.Common.Enums"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:9999/WCFServices/WCFAuthenticateUser.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:9999/WCFServices/WCFAuthenticateUser.svc?xsd=xsd4" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MYCMR.Common.Faults"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IWCFAuthenticateUser_GetHashData_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetHashData"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IWCFAuthenticateUser_GetHashData_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetHashDataResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IWCFAuthenticateUser_Verify_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Verify"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IWCFAuthenticateUser_Verify_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:VerifyResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IWCFAuthenticateUser_Authenticate_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Authenticate"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IWCFAuthenticateUser_Authenticate_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IWCFAuthenticateUser">
<wsdl:operation name="GetHashData">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/GetHashData" message="tns:IWCFAuthenticateUser_GetHashData_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/GetHashDataResponse" message="tns:IWCFAuthenticateUser_GetHashData_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Verify">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/Verify" message="tns:IWCFAuthenticateUser_Verify_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/VerifyResponse" message="tns:IWCFAuthenticateUser_Verify_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Authenticate">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/Authenticate" message="tns:IWCFAuthenticateUser_Authenticate_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/AuthenticateResponse" message="tns:IWCFAuthenticateUser_Authenticate_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFAuthenticateUser" type="tns:IWCFAuthenticateUser">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetHashData">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/GetHashData" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Verify">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/Verify" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Authenticate">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IWCFAuthenticateUser/Authenticate" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="WCFAuthenticateUser">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCFAuthenticateUser" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IWCFAuthenticateUser">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:9999/WCFServices/WCFAuthenticateUser.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```